# Quotation marks jump in next line

Tags: line-breaking, quotation

I'm writing a text and I'm using quotation marks as follows:
We will do as in the work $\glqq$ some text$\grqq$.
Now "$\grqq$" is jumping to the next line. Can I avoid this somehow?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you writing this in a (La)TeX document? Or is this in another context where you use a tool that allows you to type stuff in TeX-like syntax (e.g. a website using MathJax)? If this is in the context of a real (La)TeX document the dollar signs for math mode are not needed and should be dropped. `\glqq Hello\grqq{}` should be enough. If you are using a non-TeX-based system which supports TeX-based input this might not be an option, but questions about such systems are generally off-topic here, because they aren't TeX.

Comment: That all said, if you use real LaTeX I warmly recommend the package `csquotes`, where you can use `\enquote{some text}` to get correct language-dependent quotation marks.

Comment: FWIW I was not able to reproduce the effect your are asking about in a few quick tests I ran even if I use the dubious `$\glqq$ some text$\grqq$`. It would be great if you could post a full example document (assuming you are using LaTeX).

Comment: For example: Let me give you some example of how this does not work $\glqq$quotation is jumping into the i$\grqq$. The original code is not mine, but it is like in this example. Just forget the i in the next line. Only " is in the next line, it doesn't make sense. Unfortunately \enquote is not working...

Comment: why are you using math mode?? Also please always provide a small but complete example that shows the problem, we can not run your fragment and see the result without guessing fonts, line width etc. Impossible to guess what line breaking you are seeing.

Comment: Even with the sentence from your commend I did not manage to reproduce the effect in LaTeX, but that is not surprising as line breaking depends a lot on context in LaTeX. You really need to show us a complete example document that reproduces the issue (it might look like https://gist.github.com/moewew/829fff306c51c1969f701ff53d39a356). See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6255/35864. But note that I'm still not sure that you are really using (La)TeX.